# Clicking Links automatically when page is loaded in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to javascript and I'm working on a program that would automatically access information on a website. Currently, the program automatically logs into the site I'm testing on (ATT), but after the Log in occurs, I can't seem to find a way to get the program to open any links on the next page. It seems like once the initial login portion of the program occurs, the program stops running.

As of now, when I launch the program, it logs into my account, but after the log in occurs, it takes me to a promo offers page. I've been trying to find a way to automatically click "No Thanks" by using the URL connected to the "No Thanks" link, but was unable to do so. I have since changed the program to use `getElementByClassName()`, but I can't seem to get that to work either. I realize that `getElementByClassName()` isn't the best choice because it isn't universally supported, but I can't tell if it's not working due to it not being supported or due to my screwing it up! Here is my code below:

```
<html>
     <head>
       <title>Test</title>
       <script>
         <!--
           function login() {
              document.form1.action="https://www.att.com/olam/loginAction.olamexecute";
              document.form1.submit();
              document.action ="https://www.att.com/olam/viewInterstitialPromo.myworld";
              document.getElementByClassName("wt_BodyFormSubmit").click();
             }


         //-->
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="login()">
        <form name="form1" method="post" action="https://www.att.com/olam/loginAction.olamexecute">
          <input type="hidden" name="wireless_num"/ value = "Username">
          <input type="hidden" name="pass"/ value = "Password">
          <input type="hidden" value="dotComLogin" name="actionEvent"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="reqURI" value="/rhwc/smu">
        </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Once you've submitted your form to `www.att.com`, they're in control.  Your page is no longer loaded.  I suspect that whatever you're trying to do here is not going to be successful.  Even if you submit the form into a new window so your page remains loaded, because it's (probably) on a different domain, you won't be able to access it via JavaScript, it's a security risk.

Comment: Well that sucks. I'm assuming there are ways to do it outside of Javascript? I've seen programs out there that do similar types of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do isn't too well suited for vanilla JavaScript.  There are testing frameworks out there that are built to do what you are looking for - specifically, mimicking the interactions a human being would have with a website.

I suggest you check out [Potractor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JIGvty1bQxk&feature=youtu.be&t=552).  It does something called end to end testing - in which it simulates the click through of a website by a human being.

You'll still have to work out the security issues the target domain sets, but it's a much better place to start.